# No HDD in boot options on Asus Q500A

Tags: hard-drive, boot, asus-laptop

I have no boot options on my Asus Q500A
I've done next steps:

1. Resetted to bios options to default by f9
2. Disabled secure boot
3. Enabled CSM (added DVD-ROM to boot options)
4. Enabled PXE opROM (Added Network boot to options)
5. Switched between AHCI and IDE at SATA options

So, when i put in my usb stick in boot chapter "HDD options" line become available, but there is only usb stick here. What should i do for boot from hdd?

Answer (score 0):

This may indicate the HDD needs re-seating and will involve opening the device up to take the disk out and re-connect it. Some laptops/notebooks/netbooks have a simple cover that has a screw allowing easy access, some are a bit more involved and require an extensive dismantle...

**From having a quick look the Asus Q500A has a large panel on the underside of the laptop (shown at top of image) that allows you to access the HDD and RAM for easy upgrade!**

The job should involve a small phillips (cross-head) screwdriver.

1. Turn laptop off completely
2. Turn laptop upside down
3. Remove the battery and long panel as seen in the image below
4. The HDD may have a couple of screws securing it (remove these)
5. Slide the HDD out to make sure its connector is disconnected
6. Re-insert the HDD
7. Repeat steps 5 and 6 a couple of times to make sure the connector self-cleans (in a way)
8. Secure HDD using the screws
9. Re-install the cover plate and battery removed in step 3
10. Turn laptop back on again and see if the HDD re-appears in BIOS/boots to Windows.

[image]